# Js use ecma script 6 destructuring with "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use destructuring with the "**this**" keyword inside function/class.

I have this code:

```
class Test {
  constructor( options ) {
    let {title, content} = options;
  }
}
```

The output is (i am using babel js):

```
var _options = options;
var title = _options.title;
var content = _options.content;
```

How can i achieve this output:

```
this._options = options;
this.title = _options.title;
this.content = _options.content;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Test {
  constructor( options ) {
    ({title: this.title, content: this.content} = options);
  }
}
```

If you want the `this._options` additionally - just assign it manually.

Comment: Assuming you want to bring in all properties of `options`, you could also do `Object.assign(this, this._options = options)`.